# How to curve div using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

How to Create a div with HTML And CSS which has bottom Curved (Check Image for Reference)

[image]

If you see the image, there is an image in the background and the div ends with curve from left to right. How do we create it with CSS

I am expecting curved div at the bottom

Basically the bottom of the div must curve from left that is it goes up from left and then again goes up and down again.

I need this to be implemented in Wordpress. Anyone knows how to achieve it?

Curve is not happening in css

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code. You should also search first. This is an old and well-covered topic.